# Rails 4: strong_params,nested_attributes_for and belongs_to association trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations, nested-attributes, strong-parameters

I really can't get my head around Rails 4 strong parameters, belongs_to association and form with fields_for.

Imagine I have model for quoting some price:

```
class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :fee
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :fee
```

Now, I have seeded some fees into the db, and have put some radiobuttons on my `form_for @quote` using fields_for. The values of the radiobuttons are simply ids of the records.

Here is the troubling part, the controller:

```
def create
  @quote = Quote.new(quote_params)
  ...

end

def quote_params
  params.require(:quote).permit(:amount_from, fee_attributes: [:id])
end
```

From my understanding, automagically Rails should fetch fee record with some id, but there is some mystic error instead.

params hash is: `"quote"=>{"amount_from"=>"1200", "fee_attributes"=>{"id"=>"1"}}`

Log tail:

```
Completed 404 Not Found in 264ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Fee with ID=1 for Quote with ID=)
  app/controllers/quotes_controller.rb:14:in `create'
```

I really don't understand what is going on here, have read Rails association guide, googled for hour for all info, but to no avail.

What I want to achieve here is to understand the correct "Rails way" to fetch some associations for new Quote object using some params I've put in the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess I got nested_attributes_for wrong, somehow thought it would call Fee.find automagically.
I've opted for ditching fields_for helpers from the form and rendering fields manually like

`radio_button_tag 'fee[id]', fee.id`

Then in controller I have 2 params methods now:

```
  def quote_params
    params.require(:quote).permit(:amount_from)
  end

  def fee_params
    params.require(:fee).permit(:id)
  end
```

And my action looks like

```
 def create
    @quote = Quote.new(quote_params)
    @quote.fee = Fee.find(fee_params[:id])
    ...
```

Any additions on best practices when one has to handle lots of different objects with not so straight init logic are welcome.